# If statement does not work inside infinite loop stm32

Tags: c

I am working with a STM32F030R8T6 and the HAL libraries. I use the STM32CubeMX for all the initialization code.

When I use a "if" statement inside the infinite loop it does not work.
Eg.

```
while (1) {
    if ((Seconds - oldSec) >= 10) {
        printf("Entramos 10sec\r\n");
        oldSec = Seconds;
    }
}
```

but if a use a HAL_Delay() function it works eg.

```
while (1) {
    HAL_Delay(1);
    if ((Seconds - oldSec) >= 10) {
        printf("Entramos 10sec\r\n");
        oldSec = Seconds;
    }
}
```

I do not know, what is the problem?

I use the arm-gcc compiler with makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CubeMX provides optimization level 3 by default and this causes problems if variables are not volatile but changed outside context (like in interrupts).

Solution is to have `Seconds` and `oldSeconds` as `volatile` and make sure `Seconds` is increased in `SysTick_IRQHandler` or in `HAL_SYSTICK_Callback` functions.

Solution is also to set optimizations to level 0. But as you can see what can happen if you don't follow `volatile` rule, it is better to stay at level 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem for many times, then I realized that, if there is a single if clause in while loop problem occurs. I changed optimization level to 0 on Keil, then problem gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).